# Flutter cross-platform application, load user specific functions

Tags: flutter, cross-platform

I am creating my first Flutter-application. I was wondering if there is a way for me to let the user choose what function he/she wants. Let me give an eksample.

User1 would like to get information about the weather, while another user (user2) would like to se information about the latest news.

My problem is that i would like to load these pages from an ekstern source.

I was thinking about using a `WebView` and retrieve a html-file from my server, but is there a smarter way of doing this. Maybe a more native way?

I have a hard time explaining this one, but i hope someone have a clever idea.

Comment: Currently WebView is the way to go for that use case. There are other options discussed but not yet available. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14330 might allow that (not sure).

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to create some API endpoints (read "links that return some info") like myserver.dmn/myapp/weather , myserver.dmn/myapp/news , return data in JSON format, and use this data to build native views. I advise to read something about solutions like Firebase or Parse-server to get familiar with what are you trying to achieve. For a simplest api to play with i advise "express"